# What is the difference between the => operator and auto property?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the difference between the => operator for properties and auto property in C#?

I have properties like

```
public string Name => name;
```

but Resharper suggests that I convert them to auto properties instead:

```
public string Name { get; }
```

I do not see any added value from this. Is there any difference between the two?

Comment: The "advantage" is you dont need the field `name`

Comment: `public string Name => name;` a field initializer

Comment: `=>` is an expression equal to `get { return name; }`

Comment: `=>` gets more exciting when the RHS is not a simple field value

Comment: @SebastianHofmann;: if that is true, then the get way is just way clearer. that onle would be the "added value" of writing it like that.

Comment: @Christopher it's true, if you write the property with `{get {return...}}`, Visual Studio suggests to replace this with an expression body, aka `=>`

Answer (score 2):

The difference is that the auto property creates the backing field automatically. If you don't need it, the auto property is probably more convenient.

Comment: An auto-implemented property does create a backing field, but you can't use it in your code, it's not accessible to you.